# Appending a Table not Working in Production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a website using Bootstrap, and one of the tables has its rows removed and repopulated with new data after a button press.  It works in the testing environment in Visual Studio's Google Chrome setting, but after deployment on the live server, the table is left blank and not appended when accessed from the web.  The AJAX call is working because fields outside of the table are being updated, so I figure it might be a Java script issue between test Chrome and live Chrome.  This is my first website, so I'm not sure how to even test a specifically live application.  Does anyone know what might be causing this or can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance!

The Table:

```
<div class="row">
    <table id="dt_products" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Product ID</th>
                <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                <th class="text-center">Margin</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.Products.Any())
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Products[i].ProductID)</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Products[i].Price, "{0:c}")</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Products[i].Margin, "{0:c}")</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The AJAX Call:

```
$(function () {
    $("#ProductDate").change(function () {
        var $productValue = $("#ProductDate").val(),
            $startDate = $(".productReleaseDate"),
            $pID = { iD: $productValue };
            $('#dt_products tbody tr').remove();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Sales")',
                data: $pID,
                success: function (data) {
                    //Fill data
                    var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
                    var results = pattern.exec(data[0].ProductDate);
                    var $dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
                    $startDate.text(($dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + $dt.getDate() + "/" + $dt.getFullYear());
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var row = $('<tr></tr>');

                        idCell = $('<td class="text-center"></td>').append(data[i].ProductID);
                        row.append(idCell);

                        idCell = $('<td class="text-center"></td>').append(Number(data[i].Price).toFixed(2));
                        row.append(idCell);

                        idCell = $('<td class="text-center"></td>').append(data[i].Margin);
                        row.append(idCell);

                        $('#dt_products tbody').append(row);
                    }
                }
            });
    }).change();
});
```

EDIT: Using the Console errors in the production version, 2 errors were found.

> Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400&subset=latin-ext,latin. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

> 1:2639 Uncaught TypeError: row.app is not a function
>   at Object.success (1:2639)
>   at j (jquery.min.js:2)
>   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>   at x (jquery.min.js:4)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: It's most likely an AJAX issue. Have you checked the console for errorS?

Comment: On production you usually debug by looking to the log files, if you use some framework there is a big change you already have logs.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - thanks for the tip.  I didn't think the console on the production version would show errors to the outside world.  I've updated the question with what the Console caught.

Comment: @Keloo - thanks, I'll try to find the logs.

Comment: Both errors should be fixed, however the second one is the cause of your issue. We cannot really help you fix it though, as you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - What information should I look for?  I tried searching for any misspellings of "append" or a line including "row.app", but couldn't find any.

Comment: That's all I can suggest really. It seems that somewhere in your codebase you have a typo of `row.app`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - OK thanks.  There's no "row.app" in the page, so do you have a suggestion as to the next likely places to find it?

Comment: It's most likely your production firewall rules. It's blocking something necessary to complete the XMLHttpRequest 

Have you also tried commenting out the lines with 'row.append' ?

Comment: @AussieJoe - Thanks for the comment!  I haven't commented out the 'row.append' because wouldn't that cause the table to not repopulate and look blank as it does now?  Also, would you mind expanding on the production firewall rules?

Comment: try commenting out the 'row.append' lines to see if the error still exists? the firewall is setup by your network administrator. My guess is that your production firewall rules will be different than your development server's firewall rules.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - There actually was an accidental 'row.app' in the code.  Thanks very much for your help!  If you would summarize your comments in an answer, I'd be happy to mark it correct.

Comment: @jle glad you got it fixed. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error message it would appear that you've placed an typo of `row.app` somewhere in your code; possibly you've hit return by accident somewhere and split the line in two.

I'd suggest doing a global find in your project for `row.app` to find where the exact location of the error is.